# problem with encoding & loading in the webview

Tags: objective-c, ipad

```
    NSString *URL=[NSString stringWithString:kSearchBarURL] ;

    NSMutableURLRequest *request =  [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setHTTPBody:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"searchKeyword=%@",encodedString ] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  

    debug(@"request to be made: %@",request);

    [iWebview loadRequest:request];
```

What ever the string is entered i displaying in the webview.....

I am encoding the string which the user will enter in the text field.

Now and when entering the * / % @ # this key work in the text field its encoding ....

and displaying in the webview what i entered with the special characters.

when its come to & its not displaying in the webview.

can any one help me out

@ thanks in advance

Comment: & needs to  be &amp; are you able to verify that in your `NSString` and in the response from the post?